# How to resolve conflicts with git rebase?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I've two git branches in test. And I'm making the episode of *Rebase conflict*. However I'm too poor on git and it's easy to make a problem but hard to solve.

Now the tree of commit is like this:
[image]

What I want to do is squash commits on local `dev` and rebase `dev` to `master` (where `dev` is `-b` from `master`). Off course there will be conflicts as expected.

**Squash local**

I checked out `dev` and squashed:

[image]

[image]

Now the tree is like this:
[image]

Question 1: Why the master is off side the line instead of on some line?

**Push dev to remote**
The I want to push local to remote and before that, I pulled remote code. And surprise, local commit is override by remote:
[image]

Now the tree is below again:
[image]

Question 2: How can I push my local edit to remote?

**merge to master**
Anyway, I just want to merge code to `master` on remote. So I ignored the I-don't-understand things and created a PR on remote:
[image]
Because here is conflicts so I `rebase` master on local:
[image]
The tree turns like
[image]
I thought I can push to remote and merge now. But I run into conflicts on `dev` itself
[image]
What's tough now I cannot resolve the conflicts. These conflicts struggled with me. No matter what I tried the error exists.

Question Last: How can resolve the conflicts and rebase `master`, and merge to `master`?

Comment: Git rebase works by cherry picking. When there are conflicts, the merged changes are all staged. The conflicting changes remain unstaged in the working tree, with conflict markers. You must edit those files to remove the conflict markers. Then `git add` the resolved files to the stage and use `git rebase --continue`.    `git checkout` with no arguments will tell you what the conflicted files are. You can see them easily the `git gui` also.

Comment: To follow-up on @Kaz's comment, it's not clear from your screenshot if you actually resolved the conflicts in an editor somewhere, or if you just added the files to mark them as resolved without actually resolving them. Make sure you actually resolve them first.

Comment: I see there is a close-vote for "Needs more focus". I disagree with the close vote because although there are multiple questions, they are all related and provide good context for understanding the complete picture of what happened, and it's helpful for advising what to do about it.

Comment: @Kaz Thx for your comment. Indeed, I resolved those conflicts by remove the signs like '>>>' and '<<<'. However, the problem seems is, my local conflicts both with remote and master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question 1: Why the master is off side the line instead of on some line?

The command you ran, while having `dev` checked out, didn't have anything to do with `master`:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

You ended up squashing the top 3 commits and replaying the new squashed commit onto `HEAD~3`. If you wanted to squash those three commits *and also* replay it onto `master`, you could have done this:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3 dev --onto master

# or in this case, since HEAD~3 happens to also be the
# merge-base of dev and master, the above command simplifies to:
git rebase -i master
```

Since you would have had conflicts though, my personal preference is usually to squash first just like you did, and then do a second rebase onto the new target for resolving the conflicts, rather than trying to squash and resolve conflicts at the same time.

> I want to push local to remote and before that, I pulled remote code. And surprise, local commit is override by remote... (Implied Question 1.5: Why is that?)

This happened because you have your `pull` command configured to do a `rebase` instead of the default `merge`. So that means when you used the command `git pull` it was substituted with `git pull --rebase`, and effectively that was the same as doing:

```
git rebase origin/dev dev
```

So what happened there is it replayed all of the commits on `dev` that weren't on `origin/dev`, which was just your one new squashed commit. But all the changes in that commit were already on `origin/dev` so effectively that was the same as doing, with `dev` checked out:

```
git reset --hard @{u}

# which is just shorthand for
git reset --hard origin/dev
```

That's why your squashed commit disappeared and you ended up back where you started.

> Question 2: How can I push my local edit to remote?

Any time you rewrite your local branch that you have already pushed before, your branch will be "diverged" and this means you cannot do a regular push, but instead you must force push:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

When you tried to simply use `git push`, and Git told you to try `git pull` instead, Git was giving you bad advice. (Sometimes I tell people never to use `git pull`, partially for this reason. Instead I suggest using the separate commands of `git fetch`, then looking at the remote `origin/*` branch, and then using `git merge` or `git rebase` if desired.)

> Question Last: How can resolve the conflicts and rebase master, and merge to master?

Note the problems you had at the end were just repeating the same problems from the beginning: You rebased the 3 original commits onto `master` instead of the squashed commit. You finished resolving those conflicts (3 times instead of just once), but then made the mistake of using `git pull` again, which tried to rebase those 3 new commits onto the 3 old ones...

**What you need to do now, is:**

1. Check out `dev` and squash the 3 commits into one. (You already know how to do this.)
2. Rebase `dev` with the 1 good commit onto `master`. (`git rebase master dev`) Resolve the conflicts and then continue.
3. Force push `dev`. (`git push --force-with-lease`)
4. Create a PR to merge `dev` into `master`.

Comment: Please do not pretend that `--force-with-lease` is useful for beginners. The way in which beginners typically work with Git, it is indistinguishable from `--force`. To make the `-with-lease` part effective, a deep understanding of the workings of Git and extraordinary discipline are required.

Comment: @j6t I agree with you except I take the opposite approach. `--force` is rarely ever actually needed, so I prefer people to only learn `--force-with-lease` and even if it never helps them (compared to `--force`), it doesn't hurt. And, someday it might actually help them. At some point in the future when they learn the difference, and can take advantage of it, they'll already be in the habit of using it.

Comment: @j6t Side note: I also usually advise not to use `pull` in most cases. Once people stop pulling and fetching only on purpose, `--force-with-lease` starts becoming useful.

Comment: @TTT I've never heard of `--force-with-lease`, but I quit `pull` around 13 years ago, always using `fetch`.  This is good advice. Especially for people commited to rebase workflow, since `pull` has to be explicitly configured to default to rebase or told via the `--rebase` argument.

Comment: I see that `force-with-lease` is (1) terribly named and (2) well-intentioned but wrongheaded.  Force with lease is saying "it's okay for me to push a change that wipes out 47 items upstream, just so long as there hasn't been a #48 since I last looked".  The correct way to do this is to use `--force` and **communicate with the damn team**.

Comment: @Kaz in your example, you may need to integrate the 48th commit into your branch before force pushing, in which case you wouldn't just fetch and then run the force push again. Also, in that example it sounds like it's a shared branch, and you probably shouldn't be force pushing shared branches at all. In my teams we only force push personal branches. It's rare, but sometimes other people do collaborate on personal branches, and since we always rebase our *own* branches, if someone else added a commit to our own branch we should probably integrate it ibefore force pushing.

Comment: Caveat to my previous comment- my org also uses [gitworkflow](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows) which has a shared `next` branch that gets periodically reset. We do a regular force push of that shared branch biweekly. Of course we announce it and everyone knows. I only mention it because this conflicts with my own statement of "you probably shouldn't be force pushing shared branches at all". Obviously there's a time and a place for force pushing shared branches.

Comment: @TTT `--force-with-lease` is useful only with shared branches. Here, personal branches that are pushed to from different repositories also count as shared.

Comment: @j6t Exactly. Perhaps it's easier to state it as: Sometimes you don't realize your personal branch has become a "shared branch" because either someone else added a commit to your personal branch, or maybe you did from another copy of the repo. (e.g. working on multiple machines...)